# Visual Paradigm Sub-activity diagram icon

Tags: uml, activity-diagram, visual-paradigm

In a UML Activity Diagram, an Action representing a Sub-activity diagram can be signaled with a "trident" icon, like in this picture:

[image]

I'm using Visual Paradigm as UML editor and I need to use this icon whithin some activity diagrams. But I haven't yet realized how I can do it.

Thanks in advance to any helper.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create an action, right-click on the action and open the specification:

[image]

In the specification, select "Call Behavior Action", and in the behavior select "Create Activity", as shown below:

[image]

This will open an activity definition dialog, and after filling all details and clicking apply on all dialogs, your action will have the fork:

[image]

Enjoy.

Comment: Sorry I haven't yet found it.

Answer (score 1):

There is an easier way to do this now;

- Right click the node where you want to add the activity
- Hover over `Behaviour` and click the `Create Activity` option

After that it's just filling in the name, and creating the activity.

[image]